# How exactly are JS Case Switches supposed to be formatted?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, switch-statement, discord

So I have been working on a Discord bot for my server for a few days using Node.js and am brand new to JS. I am trying to convert some of the code from a Magic 8 Ball completed after a model for a tutorial to JS to Implement as a function (just the random number and case switch).

This is from the C# Project:

```
    switch (random.Next(4))
                                                {
                                                case 0:
                                                    Console.WriteLine("YES");
                                                    speechSynthesizer.Speak("Yes");
                                                    break;
                                                case 1:
                                                    Console.WriteLine("NO");
                                                    speechSynthesizer.Speak("No");
                                                    break;
                                                case 2:
                                                    Console.WriteLine("HELL NO");
                                                    speechSynthesizer.Speak("Hell no");
                                                    break;
                                                case 3:
                                                    speechSynthesizer.Speak("Hell yes");
                                                    Console.WriteLine("HELL YES");
                                                    break;
                                                }
```

and this is in what I am trying to implement:

```
    switch( Math.random.Next(4)) {
          case 0:
          msg.channel.send('Yes');
          break;
          case 1:
          msg.channel.send('No');
          break;
          case 2:
          msg.channel.send('Hell yes!');
          break;
          case 3:
          msg.channel.send('Hell No!');
          break;
      }
```

I am essentially trying to add a part where you can send "Magic 8 Ball", and it will return a Yes/No/Hell Yes/Hell No.

Edit:
So I followed the advice of a comment, and switched "case" to all lowercase in each instance. The error I recieve now is that math is undefined. Another article just suggested switching math to Math. next is not a function.

Comment: `case` should be in lower case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: And where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is generating a random int to use in your switch, you'll need to know how to generate a pseudorandom int in the first place.

`Math.random` generates a a float in the range of [0, 1)

So you'll need to take that value, multiply it by your max, and then floor it to turn it in to an integer.

`Math.floor(Math.random() * max)`

Your final code would look like this:

```
switch(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4))) {  // 4 is maximum n of options
      case 0:
          msg.channel.send('Yes');
          break;
      case 1:
          msg.channel.send('No');
          break;
      case 2:
          msg.channel.send('Hell yes!');
          break;
      case 3:
          msg.channel.send('Hell No!');
          break;
  }
```